# Adding filter to razor view in .ThenInclude for model

Tags: asp.net-core, filtering, razor-pages

I want to add a drop down menu filter for the view that contains clients and projects. My filter works on a single model view (Project), but I do not know how to apply the same to my OnGet action so that the resulting view is filtered on the sub-model (Project).

I have added the filter code to the OnGet action for the Project model, but do not know where to include the variable that will process the search filter.

The Index.cshtml.cs file (dsmIQ should be used to apply the filter when the user clicks on the Search button)

```
        [BindProperty]
        public List<ClientVM> ClientVMList { get; set; }

        //added for filter - start
        public string CurrentFilter { get; set; }
        //added for filter - end

        //added for filter - string searchString
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnGet(string searchString)
        {
            //added for filter - start
            CurrentFilter = searchString;
            IQueryable<Project> dsmIQ = from s in _context.Project
                                        select s;
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                dsmIQ = dsmIQ.Where(s => s.DSM.Contains(searchString));
            }
            //added for filter - end

            var clientlist = _context.Client
                .Include(c => c.ClientComments)
                .Include(p => p.Projects)
                    .ThenInclude(pc => pc.ProjectComments).ToList();

            ClientVMList = new List<ClientVM>();

            foreach (var item in clientlist)
            {
                ClientVM clientVM = new ClientVM()
                {
                    Projectlist = new List<ProjectVM>(),
                };
                clientVM.ClientName = item.ClientName;
                if (item.ClientComments != null && item.ClientComments.Any())
                {
                    clientVM.ClientStatusComment = item.ClientComments.OrderByDescending(cc => cc.LastUpdateDate).First().ClientStatusComment;
                    clientVM.ClientRAG = item.ClientComments.OrderByDescending(cc => cc.LastUpdateDate).First().ClientRAG;
                    clientVM.ClientStatusCommentId = item.ClientComments.OrderByDescending(cc => cc.LastUpdateDate).First().Id;
                }
                else
                {
                    clientVM.ClientStatusComment = "No Status Comment";
                }
                foreach (var projectItem in item.Projects)
                {
                    ProjectVM projectVM = new ProjectVM
                    {
                        ProjectPID = projectItem.PID,
                        ProjectName = projectItem.ProjectName,
                        ProjectStatusName = projectItem.ProjectStatus,
                        ForecastOwnerLongName = projectItem.ForecastOwner,
                        DSMLongName = projectItem.DSM,
                    };
                    if (projectItem.ProjectComments != null && projectItem.ProjectComments.Any())
                    {
                        projectVM.ProjectStatusComment = projectItem.ProjectComments.OrderByDescending(pc => pc.LastUpdateDate).First().ProjectStatusComment;
                        projectVM.RAGStatusName = projectItem.ProjectComments.OrderByDescending(pc => pc.LastUpdateDate).First().ProjectRAG;
                        projectVM.ProjectStatusCommentId = projectItem.ProjectComments.OrderByDescending(pc => pc.LastUpdateDate).First().Id;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        projectVM.ProjectStatusComment = "No Status Comment";
                    }
                    clientVM.Projectlist.Add(projectVM);
                }

                ClientVMList.Add(clientVM);
            }

            return Page();
```

Working code on single model (Project)

```
        public IList<Project> Project { get;set; }
        //added for filter - start
        public string CurrentFilter { get; set; }
        //added for filter - end

        //added for filter - string searchString
        public async Task OnGetAsync(string searchString)
        {
            //added for filter - start
            CurrentFilter = searchString;
            IQueryable<Project> dsmIQ = from s in _context.Project
            .Include(p => p.Client)
                                        select s;
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                dsmIQ = dsmIQ.Where(s => s.DSM.Contains(searchString));
            }
            Project = await dsmIQ.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
            //added for filter - end

            //            Project = await _context.Project
            //               .Include(p => p.Client).ToListAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Code on Index.cshtml page:

```
<form asp-page="./Index" method="get">
    <div class="form-actions no-color">
        <p>
            My projects only:
            <input type="text" name="SearchString" value="@Model.CurrentFilter" />
            <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-primary" /> |
            <a asp-page="./CommentGroupings/Index">Back to full List</a>
        </p>
    </div>
</form>
```

My View lists all projects by Client with related comments. I want the user to be able to search for all projects where their name is held (DSM field). How can I include the `IQueryable<Project> dsmIQ = from s in _context.Project` in the `.Include(p => p.Projects)` of my `var clientlist = _context.Client`?

Comment: What is your current search result and your expected result?

Comment: The code is working on the single model and provide the correct filtered result. However, when I want to apply the same to the grouped overview with the Client, ClientComment, Project and the ProjectComment models the filter is not applied at all since it is not linked to the _context.Client query. I want to apply the filter to the DSM field in my Project list only. The overview lists the models as follows: * Client1 | Comment * Project1 | Comment | DSM * Project2 | Comment | DSM * Client2 | Comment * Project1 | Comment | DSM * Project2 | Comment | DSM